# Reading until '\n' (End of Line)

Tags: c++, istream

Firstly, i'm a beginner in C++, be mercyful. I can't find an answer.

Hi, i'm trying to write a interpreter. And i select '\n' as line terminator, when i try this:

```
#define __TEST__ 1
while(Source >> Word){ //Source is file descriptor. I can't use EOF method because of if i do that, i will need to write two statments. Critical...
    if(Word == '\n'){ // Word is a string object.
        //Clean the vector
#       if __TEST__
            cout << "Succesful!" << "\n";
#       endif       
    }               
}
```

When i try to compile this code, it's gives an error because of " ' " token. When i change it with ' " ' token, compiler gives no error but when runtime, program can't detect end of line. What is the fastest way of solve this problem?

Comment: How is `Word` declared?

Comment: like "string Word;"

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz Under what circumstances do you expect the length of `Word` to be 0? Certainly not when the end of the line is reached because it will just continue reading on the next line.

Comment: @sepp2k, that is true, but given the code snippet, it seemed to be what was wanted. The question's goal is not abundantly clear.

Comment: Names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__TEST__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>>` discards white space, so `Word` won't ever contain a line break.

If you want to read until the end of the line, you should use the `getline` function rather than `>>`.

Comment: Thanks, but how i can divide it to words?

Comment: @IbrahimIpek According to the lexical rules of your language (which incidentally `>>` almost certainly wouldn't).

Comment: Minus one, because it doesn't answer his question

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz Which part of the question did I not answer? I answered both why comparing against "\n" does not work and how to correctly read until the end of the line.

Comment: @Bob__, ah, thanks, downvote removed. Well, tried, too late -- _sepp2k_ will have to edit the answer before I can remove downvote.

Comment: @IbrahimIpek use getline to read a whole line into a string, then extract the words from the string using a stringstream, for example (like [HERE](https://ideone.com/gEnO3o)). How to deal with punctuation is up to you.

Comment: @Bob__ I don't think that using `>>` to split the string by white space and then "handling punctuation" afterwards is a good approach to tokenization. It's not like the punctuation-handling code would become much more complex if it also handled spaces. And more importantly some tokens can contain white space (like string literals for example).

Comment: @sepp2k just an example (maybe poor) of how to "divide it to words". Of course, if OP is implementing an interpreter the tokenization should be different.